# Laravel 5.2 artisan error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKlFy.png)

i am using **Laravel 5.2** and **PHP 7.3.12**. and everything was working fine but today whenever i write any artisan command in laravel it gives this error:

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'`

i don't understand why its giving this error because last night it was working fine.

Comment: Did you upgrade anything recently? PHP version? Laravel version? I feel like there's incompatible code in Laravel 5.2; i.e. stuff that doesn't work with PHP 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be **No** `extra space " "` between `:` and `list`

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: The other commands are throwing the same error too, and they are correctly typed.

Comment: i know but it just for the try, see the picture it doesn't work even with no extra spaces. no commands works and give the same error always unexpected ':'

Comment: You need to check almost all your files running your application starting form the route web.php file to check where is the error .

Comment: that won't be easy. still thank you. anyone else knows a much more simpler solution i really would appreciate it.

Comment: @MuhammadKashif could you share with us your routes/web.php file ?

Comment: Thank you man. it worked. i checked the route.php and it had had a colon instead of semicolon. thank you very much user2873860.